# set onClick on the tr except for his second td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<tr class="DesignedTableTR" onclick="OpenAdPreview()">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I want that the `onclick` will be set on all the td-s except for the second td.

I know I can do it like:

```
<tr class="DesignedTableTR">
    <td onclick="OpenAdPreview()"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td onclick="OpenAdPreview()"></td>
    <td onclick="OpenAdPreview()"></td>
</tr>
```

but maybe there is another efficient way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1 is ok if you're using **jQuery**. Answer 2 is ok if you use **'modern' browsers** supporting `querySelectorAll`.

The second also has a downside: It assigns event listeners to all `<td>`s which is a quite heavy approach. Your first attempt to put the event handler only on the `<tr>` is actually more light weight (by the way, this is called **event delegation**) but there is **also** one little down side to it: you have to filter out the right element.

So if you want to stick to cross browser '**vanilla javaScript**' you might want to try the following:

First put the `this` and `event` as arguments to your function call: `onclick="OpenAdPreview(event, this)"`, then change your function `OpenAdPreview` to this:

```
function OpenAdPreview(event, that){
    var e = event || window.event,
        elm = e.target || e.srcElement,
        allTDs = that.getElementsByTagName('td');

    while (elm.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'td' && elm !== that) {
        elm = elm.parentNode; // get the right element if it's not the td already
    }

    if (elm !== allTDs[1] && elm !== that) { // this filters out your second td
        ... here goes your code
    }
}
```

`that` delivers the `<tr>` where you can look up for all `td`s with `getElementsByTagName` and then filter out.

One other (and better) way to go is to assign a class name to the `td` you don't want to click on and filter by that then: `<td class="dont-touch-me"></td>` and then in your code:

```
if ((' ' + elm.className + ' ').indexOf('dont-touch-me') < 0) { ...
```

This way you don't make your code dependent on your layout. It's then always save to change the class names of your HTML markup and your code still works as expected.

By the way: ***inline events*** are not a nice way to go. Try to stick with the traditional event handler assignments like `.addEventListener`, `.attachEvent` or the `jQuery.on()` event handling. This way you also don't have to struggle with `this`, `that` and `event`.

Added a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zxun/4/

Answer (score 11):

Another way for doing

```
<tr class="DesignedTableTR" onclick="OpenAdPreview()">
<td></td>
<td onclick="event.cancelBubble=true; return false;"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

Comment: BEST ANSWER!, why not making this as the answer for this question?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selectors.

```
$("tr.DesignedTableTR > td:not(:nth-child(2))").on("click", OpenAdPreview);
```

Answer (score 2):

well you can do this:

```
// its zero-based so second td would be at 1st index, so bind all td's onclick instead of second td
$("tr.DesignedTableTR > td:not(:eq(1))").on("click",function(){
    alert("clicked :" + $(this).html());
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5zxun/2/

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery, first you might want to stick with **event delegation** as it's more lightweight, second, you want to separate your HTML from your javaScript code, meaning: if you ever decide to make your layout different, let's say your second `<td>` should now be clickable but not your 3rd and you 7th ... then you'd have to change your code.

If you assign classes to your `<td>`s then you're fine to just change your HTML and your code will work just like expected.

```
<tr class="DesignedTableTR">
    <td></td>
    <td class="dont-toch-me"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="dont-toch-me"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

and in your code you do:

```
$("tr.DesignedTableTR").on("click", "td:not(.dont-toch-me)", function(event){
    // ... here goes your code
});
```

So, the event (and only one) sits on `<tr>` and the second argument of `.on` is your filter. This is called **event delegation**.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zxun/9/

Answer (score 1):

Plain (but "modern") JavaScript solution:

```
var tds=document.querySelectorAll("tr.DesignedTableTR td:not(:nth-of-type(2))");
var len = tds.length;
for(var i=0; i< len; i++){
    tds[i].onclick=function(){
        //.. here you go
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/5zxun/

Answer (score 1):

You can use index value of td to prevent click event as per your desire.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('tr.DesignedTableTR td').click(function(){
    if($(this).index()==1){
    ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }else{
    alert($(this).index());
    //your code here
    }
});
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zxun/1/